# How do I correct "SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list" errors?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working on a project in which I'm writing queries from this database that I am attempting to create in PLSQL. However, before I can do that I must create the db, and some of the table-create statemens I'm trying to run are returning errors. Specifically, the errors seem to indicate that some of the primary keys I'm referencing don't exist. When I check to see if that is true I see the likely issue. For example, I try to do

```
create table group_disforum ( df_id int,
ig_id int, 
constraint gdf_FK foreign key(ig_id) references Course_Interest_group(interest_gid),
constraint gdf_PK primary key(df_id, ig_id),
comments varchar(150)
)
```

setting the foreign key to the primary key(interest_gid) in Course_Interest_group. 
However, the Course_Interest_group is this:

```
create table Course_Interest_group( interest_gid int,
gname varchar(20),
courseid int,
facultyid int,
past_gpa float,
constraint IG_PK primary key(interest_gid, courseid, facultyid),
constraint IG_FK1 foreign key(courseid) references course(courseid),
constraint IG_FK2 foreign key(facultyid) references User_Faculty(userid)
);
```

The primary key for Course_Interest_group is not just interest_gid, but interest_gid, courseid, and facultyid. 
There are several other instances of the same issue. 
My question is, when referencing Course_Interest_group how can I reference just interest_gid? Is it possible? Should I change something?

I would like to keep the current Course_Interest_group pk of (interest_gid, courseid, facultyid) intact but I will modify it if needed.

[my code](http://pastebin.com/KBGGHmr5)

[my output](http://pastebin.com/EBFDmqqb)

Comment: It sounds like the three columns should be declared unique and you should have a synthetic primary key that is a single numeric column.

Comment: Ok. I'm not entirely sure what a synthetic primary key is, could you elaborate on your answer, perhaps providing or linking to an example?

Comment: Add an identity column (generally using a sequence) to assign a unique integer to each row.

Answer (score 0):

If in the course_interest_group table interest_gid uniquely identifies each row in the table then interest_gid should be the primary key. Similarly, in the group_disforum if df_id uniquely identifies each row in the table then df_id should be the primary key. Modifying the primary keys of both these tables should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way around for your question will be  a TRIGGER to customize the data Integrity. You can create a before INSERT Trigger which will check first whether the data in your case (Course_Interest_group(interest_gid)). So basic structure of your Trigger will be like. Hope this may be a workwround.

```
SET SQLBL ON;
SET DEFINE OFF;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER group_disforum_tg BEFORE
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE
    /*OF ig_id*/
    ON group_disforum FOR EACH ROW 
    DECLARE lv_chck PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO lv_chck
    FROM Course_Interest_group
    WHERE interest_gid = :new.interest_gid;
    IF lv_chck         = 0 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Parent key (interest_gid) not found in group_disforum_tg',TRUE);
    END IF;
  END;
  /
```